# MOSFET triode small-signal modeling

Tags: mosfet, switches, small-signal, transconductance

TL;DR: Why do seemingly all treatments of MOSFET small-signal operation ignore the nonzero \$g_m\$ contribution in triode? Is the implicit assumption here that if the MOSFET is operated in triode then it will be as a switch and so with a relatively constant \$V_{GS}\$, and so \$g_{m,triode}\ > 0\$ doesn't matter? I see the reasoning for this but I think in practice MOSFETs acting as switches often have significant \$V_{GS}\$ variations, e.g. when used to connect/disconnect a varying input voltage to the input of a sampling circuit.

---

My thought process behind this question: for a MOSFET in triode, we have that $$I_D = K(V_{OV}V_{DS}-V_{DS}^2/2)$$ where \$K = (W/L) \mu C_{ox}\$. If we assume "deep triode" operation where \$V_{DS} << 2 V_{OV}\$, then we have $$I_D \approx K V_{OV} V_{DS}.$$

For small-signal modeling, we generally note that $$r_o \equiv \frac{1}{\frac{dI_D}{dV_{DS}}}=\frac{1}{KV_{OV}},$$

and so use this single resistor \$r_o\$ as the entire small-signal model. However, this incremental model ignores incremental changes in the gate-source voltage, which clearly have an effect on the current. I see no reason why our small-signal model for the triode region shouldn't then include a voltage-controlled current source as in the saturation region, with value $$ g_m \equiv \frac{dI_D}{dV_{GS}} = KV_{DS}.$$

So because of the generality of the definitions of the incremental resistance and incremental transconductance, it seems that the small-signal model of the MOSFET (or any three-terminal device that can be defined by the relationship \$I = f(V_1, V_2)\$ like the MOSFET) is really the same no matter the operating condition. The difference is that depending on the operating point, the expressions for \$g_m, r_o\$ will be different.

Comment: *in practice MOSFETs acting as switches often have significant Vgs variations* Yes, but then you would not be able to use the same small signal model and gm for those situations! When a MOSFET used as a switch and the switch is **off** then the MOSFET is not in triode mode nor in saturation. It will be off and that would need it's own model (which no one is going to think about as the MOSFET is off and not doing anything).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie But I mean a switch as part of an analog circuit, like a switched-capacitor circuit. Say you want a switch to enable the input voltage to pass to the sampling circuit during some clock phase, so you pull the gate up to \$V_{DD}\$ to try to pass the input from drain to source (so that if the switch were perfectly ideal, \$V_{drain} = V_{source}\$), and the input isn't constant, it can be e.g. some kind of sinusoid. In this case the gate is fixed but \$V_{GS}\$ is varying.

Comment: Yes, \$V_{GS}\$ will be varying but as that MOSFET is supposed to work as a switch designers will make sure that the DC (constant) part of \$V_{GS}\$ is large enough so that we can keep treating the MOSFET as a (fairly constant) resistance. If that's not the case then that would introduce signal distortion. I have designed CMOS circuits for over 25 years and only ever needed to consider gm when the MOSFET is in saturation. If a transistor is in triode mode then it is usually a switch and then I don't care about gm, I just treat the MOSFET as a resistance.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I see, thank you for your insight.